# C++ 2D array and boost random number generator

Tags: c++, arrays, boost

I put in my program two loops - one fills 2D array with one value N0, and next loop is generating random number. And my program does not work when I have loop for array. I get "Unhandled exception... (parameters: 0x00000003)". But without first loop it works correctly. Thanks for help.

```
     #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>
using namespace std;


const double czas = 1E9;

int main()
{
    //Declaration of variables
    const int k = 20;
    const int L = 30;   
    double N0 = 7.9E9;
    int t,i,j, WalkerAmount;
    double excitation, ExcitationAmount;

    double slab[30][600];

    //Random number generator
    boost::random::mt19937 gen;
    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> numberGenerator(1, 4);



    //Filling slab with excitation
    for (int i = 0; i <= L; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= k*L; j++) { slab[i][j] = N0; }
    }

    //Time loop
    for (t = 0; t < czas; t++) {
        WalkerAmount = 0;
        ExcitationAmount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= L; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= k*L; j++)
            {
                int r = numberGenerator(gen);
                cout << r << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is your `slab` array defined ? Arrays in C++ are indexed from `0` to `n-1` where `n` is the capacité of the array. So the loops where you initialize `slab` might be wrong.

Comment: please mention the value of `L` and `K` ... also .... `slab[i][j] = N0;` ... what's `NO` mean?

Comment: @ThomasWillmotte `double slab[30][600]`, I tried index from `0` but it doesnt work `const int k = 20, const int L = 30 double N0 = 7.9E9`

Comment: @Witek Please, edit your post to update your code to make a minimal working example (at least something that compile). We need the definition of the array, and the definition and the values of `L`, `K` and `czas`. I guess your problem is just that you use `k*L` but we're blind without more information. You should remove the equality in the initialisation loop.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I tried do this step by step - loop with array works properly without rnadom number generator, and random number generator works properly without  array loop. I wrote here becouse I'm lack of ideas

Comment: This is C++, you don't need to declare all the variables at the beginning of the function. Declare them where you use them -- that way you won't end up with a bunch of unused (and misleading) junk (such as the top level `i`, `j`, as well as `excitation`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in C++ are indexed from `0` to `n-1` where `n` is the capacity of the array. Then, the code following code is wrong.

```
int main()
{
    //Declaration of variables
    const int k = 20;
    const int L = 30;   
    double N0 = 7.9E9;

    double slab[30][600];

    // [...]

    for (int i = 0; i <= L; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= k*L; j++) { slab[i][j] = N0; }
    }
}
```

When you initialize your array, you always go one steep too far. As you consider the case where `i == L` and `j == k*L` you reach an area in the memory that out of your array.

The loop you want to execute is

```
for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < k*L; j++)
        // Initialize
```